# After installed a laravel website on shared hosting how do you get image to display?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel website created on a VPS account that works perfectly. I needed to test the viability of getting it to work on shared hosting so I created a subdomain on a shared hosting site I support. Call it:

```
subdomain.shared-hosting.com
```

I ftp both the filesystem and database, set up the environment including .htaccess files, one in public_html and a second in the application folder.

The laravel app requires php 8.0+ but the server default is 7.4+. In the control panel I was able to point the subdomain to php8.2+. It added a handled line in the .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php82 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Added the handler to both .htaccess files. Set up the application/.env. It recognizes the db connection fine.

With laravel you have to set up the storage link. Attempting to do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

failed because of php version, 7.4 but with help I was able to do

```
/usr/local/php82/bin/php-cli artisan storage:link
```

It returned success message. Unfortunately images are not loading. Via SSH I followed the path to the storage link and it is good. Kept following to images and they are there. And since this is shared hosting we don't have root  access.

Ideas?